# Removing .orig files in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, merge, intellij-idea, kdiff3

Is there any comfortable way in IntelliJ Idea to remove all .orig files?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, .orig files are created with **hg revert** command. So you could just do **hg clean** and will wipe out the unmanaged files.

Otherwise, if you're on Mac on Linux, you could do the following using command line:

**find . -name *orig | xargs rm**

Comment: Better use `find . -name '*orig' -delete`